# C# - How to find a difference between lowest and highest numbers

Tags: c#

I have a *List* that contains multiple numbers like this:

- 1.75
- 1.25
- 2.03
- 1.44

What I want to do, is to find a difference between **lowest** and **highest** number. In this case it would be **1.25** and **2.03**, which would make **0.78**.

How should I do it?

Comment: Find the minimum, find the maximum, then subtract. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is that really difficult?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The steps are quite simple:

1. Find the largest number in the list
2. Find the smallest number in the list
3. The result you need = [Result of 1] - [Result of 2]

To implement this you can use LINQ:

```
// Intialize your list (or use the existing one)
var list = new List<decimal>{ 1.75m, 1.25m, 2.03m, 1.44m};
// The result is maximum of the list minus minimum of the list
var result = list.Max() - list.Min();
// Print or use the result
Console.WriteLine(result);  // prints the result 0.78
```

Comment: [Give a man a fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)... Please explain your code, so OP might actually learn something instead of just copy-pasting your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I added the explanation. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

first determine the maximum and the minimum number and then substract the min from the max.

Comment: how does this answer the question? And why does it have an UpVote??

Comment: @Dawood it explains the basic math, with which OP can solve their problem. It is an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I disagree this doesn't explain the logic or best way on how to find the max and min numbers from a list. This should be a comment.

Comment: @Dawood this question should not be answered in its current form anyway. This user at least did an attempt to put OP on the path towards an answer, so it is an answer. It is not required for an answer to include the exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways you can do it, but first a few questions:

1. Is the list sorted? If it is, then it's really simple.
2. If it's not sorted, then you may iterate through the list, an have two variables "min" and "max", and in the end just find the difference.
3. Are you given the list? If not and you are the one adding values to the list, then you can keep track of the added values, and assign them appropriately to your "min" and "max" variables.
4. You can use LINQ